Kafka-storage.sh is not behaving as expected in podman container
I am trying to start a Kafka(version 3.7.1) in kraft mode from an Podman image. I am able to create image without any issues. However when i am trying to run Kafka from the custom script(run.sh) which is provided below
brokerId=kafka-1
ID=$(podman run --rm --detach --network=host --name kafka --env KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1536m -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=45" --env KAFKA_OPTS="-Dlogging.level=INFO" --env KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/ocss/log4j.properties" --env REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 --env IS_DEV_SETUP=true --env ADVERTISED_HOST=${ADVERTISED_HOST} --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9093 --env HOSTNAME=$brokerId $IMAGE /ocss/entrypoint.sh)

podman ps --filter name=^/kafka$

podman logs -f $ID

This script invokes entrypoint.sh which is provided below
echo "Starting the kafka on dev setup"
    ./start-kraft.sh
    #update_kafka_configuration
    exec /ocss/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /ocss/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties --override broker.id=${HOSTNAME##*-} --override     listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9093 --override log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka/data --override compression.type=gzip \
    --override advertised.host.name=${ADVERTISED_HOST} \
    --override advertised.port=${ADVERTISED_PORT}

I am executing start-kraft.sh script from entrypoint.sh script. code for start-kraft.sh is given below
if [[ -f "/var/lib/kafka/data/meta.properties" ]]; then
         cluster_id="$(grep "cluster.id" /var/lib/kafka/data/meta.properties | awk -F '=' '{print $2}')"
         echo "existing cluster id is "$cluster_id
     else
        cluster_id="$(/ocss/kafka/bin/kafka-storage.sh random-uuid)"
        echo "new cluster id is  "$cluster_id
fi
    echo "formatting log dir"
    /ocss/kafka/bin/kafka-storage.sh format -g -t $cluster_id -c /ocss/kafka/config/kraft/server.properties
    echo "log dir formatted"

when i execute the run.sh script, logs are getting overlapped and value for cluster_id is not getting set properly and hence i am getting error while formatting log directory.error log is given below
One more thing is i am getting this error only when i am running from Podman image. I am able to start Kafka in kraft mode when i am not creating image and logs are also coming in proper sequence

Please help me here. I have already done enough research on internet about this issue but could not find anything similar to this.

After investigation i found out that kafka-storage.sh script calls StorageTool.scala class, this class extends Logging.scala class.So when we run this script by overriding the log level to Info, it prints all log statments in Info mode hence that line 'Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean' was getting printed before cluster id.
Please see class https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/3.7.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/StorageTool.scala
for more details
